# boost::python unexpected distructor behaviour

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, boost, destructor

I am creating a `boost::python` package to access c++ structure in python.
Everything is working fine but the behaviour of calling destructor by `boost::python` is quite annoying.
Don't know if there is a problem with `boost::python` module or python.

**Python version 2.7**

What i am doing is.

```
struct World
{
    void set(const std::string &msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    const std::string &greet() const { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
    World() {cout<< "CONSTRUCTOR : WORLD" << endl; }
    ~World() { cout<< "DESTRUCTOR : WORLD " << msg << endl; }
};

struct WorldData
{
    WorldData() { std::cout<< "WorldData : CONSTRUCTOR " << std::endl; my_data.clear(); }
    ~WorldData() { std::cout<< "WorldData : DESTRUCTOR " << std::endl; my_data.clear(); }
    void append_data(const World &data) { my_data.insert(my_data.end(), data); std::cout << "Data Appended\n"; }
    const vector<World> &get_data() const { return my_data; }
    vector<World> my_data;
};
```

I have created these structures and its package.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libboopyclass)
{
boost::python::class_<World>("World", boost::python::init<>())
.def("greet", &World::greet, boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::copy_const_reference>())
.def("set", &World::set);

boost::python::class_<WorldData>("WorldData", boost::python::init<>())
.def("append_data", &WorldData::append_data)
.def("get_data", &WorldData::get_data, boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::copy_const_reference>());
}
```

That is how i have created a python module. 
And calling it from python.

```
import libboopyclass

def my_module_function(input):
    print 'input : ', input
    print 'Python : Module function called'

    world_data = libboopyclass.WorldData()

    p = libboopyclass.World()
    print 'LOOP START'

    for i in range(0, 4):
        p.set("howdaadfay : " + str(i))

        world_data.append_data(p)

    del p
    print 'LOOP CLOSED'

    return world_data
```

OUTPUT :

```
LOOP START
Data Appended
DESTRUCTOR : WORLD howdaadfay : 0 // Why this destructor called
Data Appended
DESTRUCTOR : WORLD howdaadfay : 0 // Why this destructor called
DESTRUCTOR : WORLD howdaadfay : 1 // Why this destructor called
Data Appended
Data Appended
DESTRUCTOR : WORLD howdaadfay : 3 // This destructor called when variable goes out of scope
LOOP CLOSED
WorldData : DESTRUCTOR 
DESTRUCTOR : WORLD howdaadfay : 0
DESTRUCTOR : WORLD howdaadfay : 1
DESTRUCTOR : WORLD howdaadfay : 2
DESTRUCTOR : WORLD howdaadfay : 3
```

That is the problem with the destructors.
Why they got called and who call these destructors.
But if i am doing the same with c++ code. everything works fine. all destructor called when variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Maybe the boot-python library prevents the compiler from doing a copy elision? And why can't we see the constructor messages ?

Comment: I am quite surprised about the same thing. Why can't the constructor message is printed if it creates a copy of the object. :(

Comment: Why boost compiler do that?? and why the destructor of the same object called twice? and the main thing why these destructor got called if there is no call of constructor?

Comment: You don't have any call to constructor at all? THat's really strange. Is the constructor output working without python ?

Comment: No, if i do the same code with C++ without integrate with python, then its perfectly fine. Well i am still searching for the solution.. I also have done many random cases but still unable to understand this behaviour.